# Dúvidas sobre Recursividade na função MergeSort [C]

Tags: c, recursão

Eu tenho uma dúvida sobre recursividade. Na verdade, eu não estou entendendo o funcionamento. Vamos lá! Eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
void MergeSort (int *V, int inicio, int fim) {
    int meio;
    if (inicio < fim) {
        meio = floor ((inicio + fim) /2);
        MergeSort (V, inicio, meio);
        MergeSort (V, meio+1, fim);
        merge (V, inicio, meio, fim);
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é a chamada da função recursiva `MergeSort`. Até quando ele fica chamando a primeira função `MergeSort(V, inicio, meio)`  e quando ele para e começa a chamar a segunda função `MergeSort( v, meio +1, fim)`.
Eu entendo o  seguinte.

```
void MergeSort (int *V, int inicio, int fim) {
    int meio;                                                                          

    if (inicio < fim) {
        meio = floor ((inicio + fim) /2);
        MergeSort (V, inicio, meio); // chama novamente essa funcao. Pare a função que esta sendo executada

        int meio;
        if (inicio < fim) {
            meio = floor ((inicio+meio)/2)
            mergesort (V, inicio, meio) //chama novamente essa funcao. Pare a função que esta sendo executada
        }
    }
}
```

Em que momento do programa ele pararia de chamar a função `MergeSort (V, inicio , meio)` e  chamaria a função `MergeSort (V, meio+1, fim)` ?

Comment: Está faltando terminar as chaves do `if (inicio < fim) { `

Comment: Ainda resta alguma duvida sobre a questão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que o melhor meio de explicar isso seja por um gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### MergeSort

```
void MergeSort (int *V, int inicio, int fim) {
    if (inicio < fim){
        int meio;
        meio = floor ((inicio + fim) /2);
        MergeSort (V, inicio, meio); // {1}
        MergeSort (V, meio+1, fim);  // {2}
        merge (V, inicio, meio, fim);
    }
}
```

#### Explicação

1. `V[5]` **0** entra na função e calcula `meio` = **3**. Chama o primeiro MergeSort. (lado esquerdo).
2. `V[3]` **1** entra na função e calcula `meio` = **2**. Chama o primeiro MergeSort.
3. `V[2]` **2** entra na função e calcula `meio` = **1**. Chama o primeiro MergeSort.
4. `V[1]` **3** entra na função e não faz nada por causa do `if`.
5. Retoma ao `3.` chamando segunda função MergeSort.
6. `V[1]` **3** entra na função e não faz nada por causa do `if`.
7. Retoma ao `3.` chamando o `merge`.
8. Retoma ao `2.` chamando segunda função MergeSort.
9. `V[1]` **4** entra na função e não faz nada por causa do `if`.
10. Retoma ao `2.` chamando o `merge`.
11. Retoma ao `1.` chamando segunda função MergeSort. (lado direito).
12. ...
13. ...
14. ...
15. Retoma ao `1.` chamando o `merge`.
16. Retorno de `V` ordenado.

Comment: Ficou bem mais claro. Obrigado!